# GitHub Git Repository Workflow With an AWS EC2 Server?

Tags: git, github, amazon-ec2

I have a project right now that currently runs on an Amazon EC2 server.  It's an early stage project so there's no seaprate development / production environments.

My current Git setup is having a central repository on my EC2 server and having local repositories that push to this central repository on developers' laptops.  There's only one main branch on my Git repository.

I am currently migrating my central repository onto Github and I would like to have the same kind of workflow as before.  Namely, I want to be able to type in one command and then have the changes on my local repository propagate up to Github which then propagate to my EC2 server.

Right now I use

```
git push origin master
```

How do I achieve what I described above with Github in the mix?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a way to deploy to my EC2 server using [Github web hooks](https://developer.github.com/webhooks/).  Essentially, I have a PHP script (or any server side script) that runs a shell command of something like

```
git pull origin master
```

on the EC2 server.  The script is hit by Github every time I push something onto my Github repo.